# Installing apps from desktop site "play.google.com/store" not working/slow

Tags: google-play-store

When i am signed with the same account as my phone on my desktop, i can choose to install apps from my desktop. I can simply click on install button and choose the device op my preference. I remember when i did this a few years ago, it worked great. But now if it doesn't really seem to work properly. I am waiting 15 minutes for the app to shop up on my phone, but it just doesn't.

Am i doing something wrong or is it a known issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that your device is recognized correctly? To do this, go to the [Settings](https://play.google.com/settings) page and check the Last Used date. You may have multiple entries for the same device if you have switched ROMs or formatted the phone, and if you're trying to contact an old version of the phone, the install requests won't get to the device. If you have unnecessary entries here, you can hide them by unchecking the "Show in menus" checkbox.